# Can we deploy multiple services in one Corda Node?

Tags: corda

We have developed few apps in corda. Just wondering if we can deploy the different corda apps on a single node. Is it possible to do if yes then how we can proceed with this.

Currently when we deploy our application, it opens each node and run the service- state,flow for each nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a node can have several CorDapps running at once. You build and install them as follows:

- Run the following Gradle task from the root of your project to build the CorDapp JAR:

  - Unix/Mac OSX: ./gradlew jar
  - Windows: gradlew.bat jar
- Copy the CorDapp JAR from the build/libs folder to the plugins/cordapps folder of your node
- Repeat for each CorDapp

At runtime, your node will loads all the CorDapp JARs in its plugins/cordapps folder.